# Node.js / Express / mongoose backend - async operations within array.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, async-await

I am building my first solo project for a paper music magazine to offer their subscribers online reading. I already know that I will have to refactor a lot of duplicate into reusable code but I just want things to work for now.

These are the collections I use to build the models/controllers:

- Artists
- Albums
- Users (admins, authors, subscribers)
- Chronicles (album short reviews)
- Articles (album(s) long reviews)
- Interviews (related to articles most of the times)
- Issues, referencing all Chronicles, Articles and Interviews (ObjectID arrays)

*Artist* is straightforward and simple, just 'name', 'country' and an empty 'albums' array:

```
exports.createArtist = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.body.createdBy = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
  req.body.albums = []
  const newArtist = await Artist.create(req.body)

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      article: newArtist,
    },
  })
})
```

*Album* is a bit more complex, but the artist 'name' is transformed into its ObjectId for referencing, and populates the artist's 'albums' array with the newly created album ObjectId

```
exports.createAlbum = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Add createdBy automatically in the req.body
  req.body.createdBy = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)

  // Find the album's artist by its name
  const relatedArtist = await Artist.findOne({ name: req.body.artist })

  if (!relatedArtist) {
    return next(new AppError('No artist with that name, please check', 404))
  }
  // replace the name of the artist with its objectID for auto referencing
  req.body.artist = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(relatedArtist._id)

  // save album
  const newAlbum = await Album.create(req.body)

  // add the saved album into the albums' array in the artist collection
  relatedArtist.albums.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newAlbum._id))
  await relatedArtist.save()

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      album: newAlbum,
    },
  })
})
```

Chronicle is a bit similar but involves 3 other collections in the process: collection of album & artist data, and populating the 'chronicles' array of the current issue:

```
exports.createChronicle = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Add author automatically in the req.body
  req.body.author = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)

  // Find artist & album of the chronicle in the respective collections
  const artist = await Artist.findOne({ name: req.body.artist })
  const album = await Album.findOne({ title: req.body.album })
  const issue = await Issue.findOne({ issueNumber: req.body.belongsToIssue })

  if (!artist) {
    return next(new AppError('No artist with that name, please check.', 404))
  }
  if (!album) {
    return next(new AppError('No album with that name, please check.', 404))
  }
  if (!issue) {
    return next(new AppError('No issue with that number, please check.', 404))
  }

  // replace the name of the artist and album with its objectID for auto referencing
  req.body.artist = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(artist._id)
  req.body.album = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(album._id)

  // Create Chronicle unique slug & add to req.body
  req.body.slug = slugify(`${artist.name} ${album.title} ${album.year}`, {
    lower: true,
  })

  // Save new Chronicle
  const newChronicle = await Chronicle.create(req.body)

  // Push new Chronicle ID into the array of the corresponding Issue
  issue.chronicles.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newChronicle._id))
  await issue.save()

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      chronicle: newChronicle,
    },
  })
})
```

My problem comes now for 'Articles' :
An article can be about **several** albums (so not just an ObjectId, but an array of ObjectIds!) and can be signed by **several** writers (between 1 and 3). I have to loop through both arrays while performing each time:

```
await Album.find({title: req.body.title})
await User.find({author: req.body.author})
```

then swap the names in the req.body.albums & req.body.authors by its ObjectId and in the end, transforming the req.body.albums + authors from an array of strings into an array of ObjectIds, especially where arrays are pointers (I'm guessing I have to work with a destructured duplicate array).
I understood that I can't perform async operations within a *forEach()* of *map()* loop but haven't figured out how to make this work. My research makes me think I have to use *Promise.all()* but haven't figured out how to so far, all my trials and errors failed until now, so I must do this the wrong way or don't understand the process.

Thank you for the help and tricks!

Comment: Something like this `const albums = await Promise.all(titles.map(title => Album.find({title: title})))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Anatoly. Your tip led me to something that needs to be optimized and refactored but that has the huge advantage of being totally functional:

```
exports.createArticle = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Add authors automatically in the req.body if not specified by user
  if (!req.body.authors || req.body.authors === []) {
    req.body.authors.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id))
  }

  // loop through all authors names and swap with respective ObjectIds
  const tempAuthors = []
  await Promise.all(
    req.body.authors.map(async (author, index) => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ name: author })
      if (!user) {
        return next(
          new AppError(
            `No author with that name (position ${index + 1}), please check.`,
            404
          )
        )
      }
      tempAuthors.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id))
    })
  )

  // Assign req.body.authors the values of tempAuthors
  req.body.authors = [...tempAuthors]

  // loop through all album titles and swap with respective ObjectIds
  const tempAlbums = []
  await Promise.all(
    req.body.albums.map(async (title, index) => {
      const album = await Album.findOne({ title })
      if (!album) {
        return next(
          new AppError(
            `No album with that title (position ${index + 1}), please check.`,
            404
          )
        )
      }
      tempAlbums.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(album._id))
    })
  )

  // Assign req.body.authors the values of tempAuthors
  req.body.albums = [...tempAlbums]

  // Find artist & issue of the article
  const artist = await Artist.findOne({ name: req.body.artist })
  if (!artist) {
    return next(new AppError('No artist with that name, please check.', 404))
  }

  const issue = await Issue.findOne({ issueNumber: req.body.belongsToIssue })
  if (!issue) {
    return next(new AppError('No issue with that number, please check.', 404))
  }

  // replace the name of the artist with its objectID for auto referencing
  req.body.artist = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(artist._id)

  // Create Article unique slug & add to req.body
  req.body.slug = slugify(
    `${issue.issueNumber} ${artist.name} ${req.body.title}`,
    {
      lower: true,
    }
  )

  // Save new Article
  const newArticle = await Article.create(req.body)

  // Push new Article ID into the array of the corresponding Issue
  issue.articles.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(newArticle._id))
  await issue.save()

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      article: newArticle,
    },
  })
})
```

The next step will be to outsource the swap function for Albums and Authors to avoid duplicate code.